# reveal.js: ReferenceError: navigator is not defined on fresh install

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, reveal.js

I am trying to use reveal.js in my React.js/Next.js website based on this
https://revealjs.com/installation/#installing-from-npm

The error I get is:

```
Server Error

ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source

external%20%22reveal.js%22 (1:0) @ eval

> 1 | module.exports = require("reveal.js");
```

I read through the entire reveal site and searched, there is no reference to navigator or dependencies anywhere.

This is my code, (the CSS is included in my `_app.js`):

```js
import Head from 'next/head'
import Link from 'next/link'
import ContainerFull from '../components/container-full'
import MoreStories from '../components/more-stories'
import HeroPost from '../components/hero-post'
import Intro from '../components/intro'
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import { getHomePage, getHomeSlides } from '../lib/api'
import { CMS_NAME } from '../lib/constants'
import Header from '../components/header'
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const MySlides = dynamic(
  () => import('../components/slides'),
  { ssr: false }
)

export default function Page( {page, artwork} ) {
   return (
    <>
      <Layout>
        <Head>
          <title>{ page.seo.title }</title>
          <meta name="description" content={page.seo.metaDesc} />
        </Head>
        <Header />
        <ContainerFull>
          <h1>{ page.title }</h1>
          <MySlides />
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: page.content }} />

          {artwork.nodes && artwork.nodes.map((arts) => (
            <span>{arts.title}</span>
          ))}
        </ContainerFull>
      </Layout>
    </>
  )
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const data = await getHomePage()
  console.log(data)
  const art = await getHomeSlides()
  console.log(art)

  return {
    props: {
      page: data,
      artwork: art,
    },
  }
}
```

`slides.js` file

```
import Reveal from 'reveal.js'
import Markdown from 'reveal.js/plugin/markdown/markdown.esm.js'
import React, { useEffect } from "react"

const MySlides = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    let deck = new Reveal({
        plugins: [ Markdown ]
    })
    deck.initialize()
  })

  return (
    <div>SlideShow</div>
  )
}

export default MySlides
```

Comment: It most likely refers to `window.navigator` which is only available in the browser, but Next also renders on the server where `window` is undefined (so `navigator` is also undefined). You need to check to make sure you're on the client, not the server, and then include any client-only code.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for responding.. there isn't any other code provided.. I kind of understand what you are saying, but I have no idea how to proceed from here based on what you said

Comment: What's happening is that Next is trying to run the Reveal code on the server and an error is thrown because Reveal needs a window/browser, but the server doesn't have one. This is happening in your `deck.initialize();` - it's trying to initialize Reveal on the server. Try moving it to a `useEffect` because that only runs on the client/browser, or try wrapping it in a statement that checks for the window (like `if( typeof window !== 'undefined' )`). Also check out https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr

Comment: I should add - how you have it now, `deck.initialize();` will try to run on the server and then again on the client. You need to modify your code a bit to make sure it _only_ runs on the client.

Comment: So I tried this, it brings me back to the original error

const MySlides = () => {
 
 useEffect(() => {
   
  let deck = new Reveal({
     plugins: [ Markdown ]
  })
  deck.initialize();

   })

   return (
      <div>SlideShow</div>
   )
 
}

Comment: I updated my code above... I took the slide code and put it in its own file.. the new error is Unhandled Runtime Error

TypeError: e is null   plugins: [ Markdown ]
  12 |   })
> 13 |   deck.initialize();
     |       ^
  14 | 
  15 |    })

Comment: they have this disclaimer, would it be safe to say I cant use it this way "The framework is published to, and can be installed from, npm. Note that reveal.js is targeted at the browser and includes CSS, fonts and other assets so the npm dependency use case may be limited."

Answer (score 2):

Since `Reveal` and `Markdown` are client side modules which depend on `navigator` object, it's incorrect to import it in the first two lines. Instead, they should be imported in the `useEffect` block, as the block will be run in the client side according to the document at https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/client-side.

This is what works for me:

```js
import { useEffect } from "react"

const MySlides = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // This will be executed in the browser (client-side).
    const clientSideInitialization = async () => {
      // load modules in browser
      const Reveal = await (await import("reveal.js")).default
      const Markdown = await (await import("reveal.js/plugin/markdown/markdown.esm")).default
      const deck = new Reveal({
        plugins: [Markdown]
      })
      deck.initialize()
    }
    clientSideInitialization()
  })

  return (
    <div>SlideShow</div>
  )
}

export default MySlides
```

Comment: You don't need the double `await` when dynamically importing `Reveal` and `Markdown` - `(await import("npm-package")).default` should be enough.

Comment: It has to be double `await`. But I've just found a different way to put it from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#importing_defaults:

`const { default: Reveal } = await import("reveal.js")`

Comment: The double await is absolutely not needed, the following will work just as well: `const Reveal = (await import("reveal.js")).default`. I do agree that `const { default: Reveal } = await import("reveal.js")` is a much more readable way of doing it though.